# Query is missing results

Tags: sql, db2, subquery

The original query pulls all of the correct data. The sub-query pulls all of the data correctly separately. When put together, the full query misses like 8 rows.

```
SELECT 
    TMRQD,
    TMCUST,
    TMNAME,
    S3ON,
    S3ORQT,
    S3ITNO,
    IMDESC,
    S3DTSTO,
    S3DTNSEQ# 
FROM 
         TSA400.NRPDTA.S3C S3O RIGHT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.SOP114F1 SOP114F1 ON S3O.S3ON = SOP114F1.TMON
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.S3DTU S3DTU ON SOP114F1.TMON = S3DTU.S3DTON
        INNER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.IMA IMA ON S3O.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO
    WHERE
          S3DTNSEQ# = (
    SELECT
          MAX(S3DTNSEQ#)
    FROM 
        TSA400.NRPDTA.S3C S3O_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.SOP114F1 SOP114F1_1  ON S3O_1.S3ON = SOP114F1_1.TMON
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.S3DTU S3DTU_1 ON SOP114F1_1.TMON = S3DTU_1.S3DTON
        INNER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.IMA IMA_1 ON S3O_1.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO
    GROUP BY
             S3ITNO)

    OR S3DTNSEQ# IS NULL

    GROUP BY
            TMRQD,
            TMCUST,
            TMNAME,
            S3ON,
            S3ORQT,
            S3ITNO,
            IMDESC,
            S3DTSTO,
            S3DTNSEQ# 
ORDER BY S3ON
```

What would be causing the query to miss only a few order numbers?

Comment: Have you looked at which 8 rows are missing, and determined what is special about those rows? (this questions is difficult to answer without DDL and data, but perhaps someone smarter than me will be able to spot a flaw in the SQL).

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` on every column? Should you use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead?

Comment: Generally speaking, style wise, your `FROM` clause should always be assumed to have a row.  If you're immediately following it up with `RIGHT JOIN`, you want to flip the references and use `LEFT JOIN` instead.  You appear to be doing a [tag:greatset-n-per-group] query, of which there's a couple other options; knowing your table structure and data may help us suggest other things to try.

Answer (score 0):

in your subquery you use alias without "_1" in the last inner condition:

```
INNER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.IMA IMA_1 ON S3O_1.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO
```

Add copy your outer condition "`S3O_1.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO`" to where

So, the result will be

```
SELECT 
    TMRQD,
    TMCUST,
    TMNAME,
    S3ON,
    S3ORQT,
    S3ITNO,
    IMDESC,
    S3DTSTO,
    S3DTNSEQ# 
FROM 
         TSA400.NRPDTA.S3C S3O RIGHT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.SOP114F1 SOP114F1 ON S3O.S3ON = SOP114F1.TMON
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.S3DTU S3DTU ON SOP114F1.TMON = S3DTU.S3DTON
        INNER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.IMA IMA ON S3O.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO
    WHERE
          S3DTNSEQ# = (
    SELECT
          MAX(S3DTNSEQ#)
    FROM 
        TSA400.NRPDTA.S3C S3O_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.SOP114F1 SOP114F1_1  ON S3O_1.S3ON = SOP114F1_1.TMON
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.S3DTU S3DTU_1 ON SOP114F1_1.TMON = S3DTU_1.S3DTON
        INNER JOIN TSA400.NRPDTA.IMA IMA_1 ON S3O_1.S3ITNO = IMA_1.IMITNO
    WHERE S3O_1.S3ITNO = IMA.IMITNO
    GROUP BY
             S3ITNO)

    OR S3DTNSEQ# IS NULL

    GROUP BY
            TMRQD,
            TMCUST,
            TMNAME,
            S3ON,
            S3ORQT,
            S3ITNO,
            IMDESC,
            S3DTSTO,
            S3DTNSEQ# 
ORDER BY S3ON
```

Comment: Yes, but changing to use the alias would cause it throw an error, when the subquery almost certainly returns more than one row.  OP needs to add an additional condition somewhere, or try something else.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse. No It'll be ok, cause Ike Diaz use MAX(S3DTNSEQ#) and group by in subquery.

Comment: Except it's the `GROUP BY` that's the problem.  Without some condition tying it to the outer row, you're going to end up with multiple "max" values - one for each different `s3itno`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse. Topic starter wrote "The sub-query pulls all of the data correctly separately" So his subquery with group by was right, before someone had suggested him to add outer tying and he had changed one of join condition. I think it was wrong. If he needs to use outer tying - bettter to add extra where condition. Changed solution with this preposition